# Styles not being applied to all controls in container

Tags: wpf, styles

I have window with a Grid control with four columns and four rows. It contains the following:

```xml
<Label Name="HeightLabel" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Height" Target="{Binding ElementName=HeightValue}"/>
<TextBox Name="HeightValue" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center"/>

<Label Name="WeightLabel" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Weight" Target="{Binding ElementName=WeightValue}"/>
<TextBox Name="WeightValue" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center"/>

<Label Name="WidthLabel" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Width" Target="{Binding ElementName=WidthValue}"/>
<TextBox Name="WidthValue" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center"/>

<Label Name="LengthLabel" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Length" Target="{Binding ElementName=LengthValue}"/>
<TextBox Name="LengthValue" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

with the following style applied in the Resource Dictionary:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Border>
                    <ContentPresenter TextBlock.FontSize="18"
                                      TextBlock.Foreground="Red" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem is only the last label control is being styled; the rest receive the default TextBlock style. I know the Label contains an embedded TextBlock which makes styling more difficult than most other controls, so I suspect there's some kind of hierarchy issue going on, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Comment: I don't want to answer my own question -- yet -- but apparently, the Label control requires the access key be set on its Content text. The last element's Content was being set via code. When I set the text for the other Label controls, including the access key in each, it worked. I'm also guessing it works when no access keys are set at all. Perhaps I should amend my question: why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment above, the problem is when an access key accelerator is not specified, the Label is rendered as a TextBlock, thus my Label style was not being applied.

Answer (score 2):

They all get styled on my screen, when using a VALID Style. Yours have several problems, such as Foreground="{Red}" instead of Foreground="Red", and missing a />

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Border>
                    <ContentPresenter TextBlock.FontSize="18"
                                      TextBlock.Foreground="Red" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```